# Retrieve a particular value from a matrix in SSRS 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have showing value of 5 categories month-wise (4 months) in matrix like as follow:

```
CategoryA 1 2 3 4

CategoryB 4 5 8 0

CategoryC 2 4 6 7

CategoryD 9 5 4 5

CategoryE 5 4 8 5
```

Now I have added 1 column (Outside group) in right showing total row-wise. What I am going to ask is that I want to add a row (outside group) to show percentage **(Category D / CategoryA * 100)** month wise (against all 4 column and "total" Column)

Please suggest .....

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to the following steps:

1. Create a calculated column let’s say `CategoryDValue` in the dataset and use this expression `=IIF(Fields!Category.Value=” Category D”,Fields!MonthData.Value,0)`
2. Now in the outside group column cell use this expression `=(SUM(Fields! CategoryDValue.Value) / SUM(Fields!MonthData.Value)) * 100`